# Subscribing to fetch a nested array

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I have an object and its properties as following:

```
class Section {

 var cards: [MemberCard]

 init(card: [MemberCard]) {

 }
}

class MemberCard {
  var name: String
  var address: String?
  init(name: String) {
     self.name = name
  }
}
```

I'm subscribing to a RxStream of type Observable<[Section]>. Before I subscribe I would to want flat map this function.

where the flat map would perform the following actions:

```
let sectionsStream : Observable<[Section]> = Observable.just([sections])
sectionsStream
.flatMap { [weak self] (sections) -> Observable<[Section]> in
  for section in sections {

     for card in section.cards {

     }
   }
 }.subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] (sections) in

    self?.updateUI(memberSections: sections)

}).disposed(by: disposeBag)

func getAddressFromCache(card: MemberCard) -> Observable<MemberCard> {
   return Cache(id: card.name).flatMap ({ (card) -> Observable<MemberCard> in
      asyncCall{

         return Observable.just(card)   
      }

   }
}
```

How would the flatmap look like when it comes to converting `Observable<[Section]>` to array of `[Observable<MemberCard>]` and back to `Observable<[Section]>`?

Comment: Where do you call `getAddressFromCache`? What are you trying to achieve? Why do you want to "flat map this function."?

Comment: How would you handle error scenario(s) when at least one of the cards cannot be fetched?

Answer (score 0):

Technically, like that -

```
let o1: Observable<MemberCard> = ...
let o2: Observable<Section> = omc.toList().map { Section($0) }
let o2: Observable<[Section]> = Observable.concat(o2 /* and all others */).toList()
```

But I do not think it is an optimal solution, at least because there is no error handling for the case when one or more cards cannot be retrieved. I would rather build something around aggregation with `.scan()` operator as in https://github.com/maxvol/RaspSwift

Comment: Redux like systems are crazy simple with Rx. Here's another one: https://github.com/dtartaglia/RxMultiCounter/blob/master/RxMultiCounter/RxExtensions/Store.swift The entire system is in one file.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
extension ObservableType where E == [Section] {
    func addressedCards() -> Observable<[Section]> {
        return flatMap {
            Observable.combineLatest($0.map { getAddresses($0.cards) })
        }
        .map {
            $0.map { Section(cards: $0) }
        }
    }
}

func getAddresses(_ cards: [MemberCard]) -> Observable<[MemberCard]> {
    return Observable.combineLatest(cards
        .map {
            getAddressFromCache(card: $0)
                .catchErrorJustReturn($0)
        })
}
```

If one of the caches emits an error, the above will return the MemberCard unchanged.

I have a couple of other tips as well.

- In keeping with the functional nature of Rx, your `Section` and `MemberCard` types should either be structs or (classes with `let`s instead of `var`s).
- Don't use `String?` unless you have a compelling reason why an empty string ("") is different than a missing string (nil). There's no reason why you should have to check existence *and* isEmpty every time you want to see if the address has been filled in. (The same goes for arrays and Dictionaries.)

For this code, proper use of `combineLatest` is the key. It can turn an `[Observable<T>]` into an `Observable<[T]>`. Learn other interesting ways of combining Observables here: https://medium.com/@danielt1263/recipes-for-combining-observables-in-rxswift-ec4f8157265f